# How to skip the ReferenceAccess constraint on a file upload by an anonymous user?

Tags: forms, 8, files

I have a contact form for job applications with a file field on it so users can upload their CV. Because of privacy / security, the uploaded CV's must be stored in the private filesystem.

Unfortunately, a problem occurs when an anonymous user tries to add a CV and submit the form. Since the anonymous user does not have access to the uploaded file, the file field's ReferenceAccess constraint (`\Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\Validation\Constraint\ReferenceAccessConstraint`) kicks in and throws a validation error: `You do not have access to the referenced entity (file: 1)`. As a consequence, the user is not allowed to submit the form.

Is there a way to tell Drupal to skip the ReferenceAccess constraint when anonymous users reference a file that they just uploaded themselves?

Update: I came to realize that this does not happen when using the core  file field, only with the File Entity module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That constraint is validated by [`\Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\Validation\Constraint\ReferenceAccessConstraintValidator`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Plugin%21Validation%21Constraint%21ReferenceAccessConstraintValidator.php/class/ReferenceAccessConstraintValidator/8.5.x). [`ReferenceAccessConstraintValidator::validate`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Plugin%21Validation%21Constraint%21ReferenceAccessConstraintValidator.php/function/ReferenceAccessConstraintValidator%3A%3Avalidate/8.5.x) uses the following code.

```
  /* @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityInterface $referenced_entity */
  $referenced_entity = $value->entity;
  if ($referenced_entity) {
    $entity = $value->getEntity();
    $check_permission = TRUE;
    if (!$entity->isNew()) {
      $existing_entity = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage($entity->getEntityTypeId())->loadUnchanged($entity->id());
      $referenced_entities = $existing_entity->{$value->getFieldDefinition()->getName()}->referencedEntities();

      // Check permission if we are not already referencing the entity.
      foreach ($referenced_entities as $ref) {
        if (isset($referenced_entities[$ref->id()])) {
          $check_permission = FALSE;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    // We check that the current user had access to view any newly added
    // referenced entity.
    if ($check_permission && !$referenced_entity->access('view')) {
      $type = $value->getFieldDefinition()->getSetting('target_type');
      $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, [
        '%type' => $type,
        '%id' => $id,
      ]);
    }
  }
```

(In particular, see the line containing `$referenced_entity->access('view')`.)

We can hook into the file's access control to alter the outcome, with [`hook_entity_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_access/8.5.x) or [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access/8.5.x).

Another solution could be to create a new field type which inherits everything from [`Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileItem`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21FileItem.php/class/FileItem/8.5.x), except for the `ReferenceAccess` constraint in its plugin definition. You can do this in two ways:

1. Create a new plugin class that extends the original class, and copy and modify its docblock, including the `@FieldType` annotation.
2. Implement [`hook_field_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_info_alter/8.5.x), copy the `file` plugin definition to your own, and make the necessary adjustments there.

Comment: Thank you. Extending the FieldItem class is a solution I was already considering, and it does indeed work. Implementing `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access` works as well. However with either method I wonder if I am creating security holes. What are the possible risks and how could we prevent them?

Comment: Yes, you are. At the moment the file is uploaded, even before submit. That the file is private does not protect it from getting downloaded by the owner. And this is any anonymous user with uid 0, if he can guess the filename.

Comment: Since the private file can be viewed only by the owner, you just have to change the owner in the submit function.

Comment: That would help, but not for files that are not yet submitted. For this you can use hook_file_download: `if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) { return -1; }`