# How do I use hook_entity_access() to let anonymous users upload private files?

Tags: files, users

I have same issue described in 
[How to skip the ReferenceAccess constraint on a file upload by an anonymous user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215608/how-to-skip-the-referenceaccess-constraint-on-a-file-upload-by-an-anonymous-user)
So I need to use `hook_entity_access()` or `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access()` to solve the issue.

What code should I use inside the hook?